# Разбить строку на массив по шаблону

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Из строки:

```
word ~~apple smile ~~string site ~~sun
```

Нужно получить массив с `array('apple', 'string', 'sun');` , т.е. слова, перед которыми есть спец. символы `~~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. На всякий случай привел пример поиска слов как с `~~`, так и без них. `preg_match_all` возвращает в третьем параметре список вхождений в соответствующем круглым скобкам подмассиве, т.е. в нашем случае в `$match[1]` лежит готовый массив всех слов:

```
<?php
    $str = "word ~~apple smile ~~string site ~~sun";
    if (preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)~~([^\s]+)/', $str, $match))
    {
         print "Слова ~~ найдены:\n";
         print_r($match[1]);
    }
    if (preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)(?!~~)([^\s]+)/', $str, $match))
    {
         print "Найдены следующие слова без ~~:\n";
         print_r($match[1]);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'word ~~apple smile ~~string site ~~sun';
$tempArr = explode(' ', $string);
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($tempArr as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, '~~') === 0) {
        $resultArr []= substr($value, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам помогут регулярные выражения:

```
$str = 'word ~~apple smile ~~string site ~~sun';
preg_match_all('/~~(\w+)/', $str, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

Comment: Ваш вариант найдет так же слова в середине которых есть ~~, хотя конечно маловероятно, что они будут